# function rowCount() on a non-object error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I keep getting an **`function rowCount() on a non-object`** error on two different pages. Any idea why this is happening and how I can alter the code to prevent it from happening?

**Error - as below**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/index.php on line 35
```

**The code:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * from idea ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 50;";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);

if($result->rowCount() > 0 && !empty($result)) // line 35
{
    foreach ($result as $row) 
    {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $idea = $row['idea'];

    echo '<span class="idea" id="'.$id.'"><strong style="color: #0081C5">' . $title . "</strong>&nbsp;-&nbsp;" . $idea . '&nbsp;<a class="delete" href="#">[Delete]</a></span>';
    }
}
```

**Error - as below**

**`Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/assets/update.php on line 6`**

**The code**

```
 $sql = "SELECT * from idea ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 50;";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);

if($result->rowCount() > 0 && !empty($result)) // line 6
    {
        foreach ($result as $row) 
        {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $idea = $row['idea'];

        echo '<span class="idea" id="'.$id.'"><strong style="color: #0081C5">' . $title . "</strong>&nbsp;-&nbsp;" . $idea . '&nbsp;<a class="delete" href="#">[Delete]</a></span>';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change it to this

`if(!empty($result) AND $result->rowCount() > 0)`

Comment: Can you explain why? (For the good of OP and future visitors)

Comment: his code first checks if result is not empty and THEN only tries calling rowCount on it.